# consider something suspect -- is it okay to say it like that?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Example with a context:

> People expect that same familiarity when it comes to software applications. If you go to
>   pizzahut.com to order lunch and don’t see the red roof logo, you will probably **consider the site suspect** and order somewhere else. There is comfort in familiarity. When you develop your Access applications, you will likely have to deal with the necessity for branding.

Is this a legitimate grammar pattern? Could you please give me some more examples with this structure?

Comment: Could you add the source or a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Consider something suspect", meaning "to regard something as suspicious", is absolutely legitimate.  I wouldn't even regard this phrasing as idiomatic (regard as, or view as, also work), although it is a pretty common formulation:  "suspect" here means "regarded with suspicion or distrust" or "that is an object of suspicion", and "consider" is used in its common meaning of "regard in a certain light".

It could be used in really any number of contexts where suspicion or doubt about a thing is being conveyed:  You might consider some food suspect if smells off.  You might consider someone's explanation suspect if you have evidence to the contrary.  From the OED: "In tropical regions,..all water should be looked upon as suspect and treated accordingly." You might consider a person suspect if he's peering into your car.  As far as I can think of, anything that one might view with suspicion for any reason could correctly be "considered suspect".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that usage is OK. I would use *would* instead.

> ...you **would** probably consider the site suspect...

because "probably" is not certainty.

Comment: Hmm, *you will probably consider ...* sounds fine to my native ear ...

Comment: @Araucaria Depends on the context. You could say "As you investigate the crime, you *will probably consider* many factors." But in the example, we are not sure who would necessarily consider what is being stated.

Comment: *If you go to Pizzahut.com, you'll probably find the site suspect* seems ok to me ... But that might be my BE ear.