# What is the difference between "suspicious" and "suspect"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between "suspicious" and "suspect"? Which option is correct, "The witness's claim was suspect." or "The witness's claim was suspicious."?

Comment: Please look those up in a dictionary before asking us here. Thanks.

Comment: A century ago, [***claims** were always **suspicious***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=claim+is+suspect%2Cclaim+is+suspicious&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), but they're usually ***suspect*** today. For something like a ***claim*** (that we might not trust), it's inconceivable we have radically different ways of thinking about its "trustworthiness", so my linked chart simply proves that we now use a different word for the same situation. But in some *other* contexts, the two words have diverged in both meaning and syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [consider something suspect -- is it okay to say it like that?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49301/consider-something-suspect-is-it-okay-to-say-it-like-that)  Also [Difference between "suspected", "a suspect" and "suspicious"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109782/) and ["Suspect someone" VS "Be suspicious of someone"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266011/), among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any difference in meaning, it is subtle. My intuition is that "suspicious" emphasizes that the witness's character or motives are in question. "The claim is suspect" is a fairly idiomatic way to say that there is reason to doubt that it is true.

If I had reason to believe that somebody accidentally sent me incorrect information, but was not trying to mislead, I would probably say the information was "suspect", not "suspicious".

Comment: I agree your distinction. It's not really relevant to the marked shift over time between ***suspect / suspicious claims*** (we now just use a different word in that context, which hasn't changed), but in general, ***suspect*** has come to mean *possibly not true / reliable / functional* (for *any* reason, including *none*), with ***suspicious*** increasingly connoting ***deliberately** dishonest / illegal* activity.